# How to remove levels from a multi-indexed dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

For example, I have:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([8, 9],
                          index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 1, 1),
                                                           (1, 3, 2)]),
                          columns=['A'])

In [2] df
Out[2]: 
       A
1 1 1  8
  3 2  9
```

Is there a better way to remove the last level from the index than this:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(df.values,
                     index=df.index.droplevel(2),
                     columns=df.columns)
Out[3]: 
     A
1 1  8
  3  9
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
df.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
Out[29]: 
     A
1 1  8
  3  9
```

Comment: Worth noting, that there is an inplace argument, which is `True` would modify `df` rather than returning a new DataFrame.

Comment: This works right now, even in a `pd.Series`. The `.index.drop(...)` ideas may be obsolete.

Comment: If your index level 1 is miningful and not just the perfect range of numbers you will be reseting the level 1 too?

Answer (score 76):

You don't need to create a new DataFrame instance! You can modify the index:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(2)
df

     A
1 1  8
  3  9
```

You can also specify negative indices, for selection from the end:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(-1)
```

Comment: can this be applied to columns for pandas v 0.23+?

Comment: I've just tried it with v 0.22 and worked for columns. I like this answer better than the accepted one. It is clearer for me, and can be applied to columns as well.

Answer (score 12):

If your index has names like

```
       A
X Y Z
1 1 1  8
  3 2  9
```

Then you can also remove by specifying the index name

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel('Z')
```

Answer (score 3):

From 0.24+, we can directly [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) on `df`. So, to drop the last level of the index:

```
>>> df

         col
1 5 1 4  foo
  3 2 8  bar
2 4 3 7  saz

>>> df.droplevel(-1)

       col
1 5 1  foo
  3 2  bar
2 4 3  saz
```

The axis whose levels are dropped can also be controlled with `axis` argument and it defaults to 0, i.e., over index. Multiple levels can be dropped at once via supplying a list and if any of the index has a name, those can be used, too (as exemplified in the linked doc).

---

Note: the argument to `droplevel` is tried to be first interpreted as a *label*; so if any of the levels happens to have an integer name, it will be dropped i.e., not positionally:

```
>>> df
                 col
this -1 other 0
1    5  1     4  foo
     3  2     8  bar
2    4  3     7  saz


# literally drops `-1` level
>>> df.droplevel(-1)

              col
this other 0
1    1     4  foo
     2     8  bar
2    3     7  saz

# literally level `0` is dropped
>>> df.droplevel(0)

               col
this -1 other
1    5  1      foo
     3  2      bar
2    4  3      saz
```

To make sure a positional dropping happens, we can go for the `names` attribute and select positionally there:

```
>>> df
                 col
this -1 other 0
1    5  1     4  foo
     3  2     8  bar
2    4  3     7  saz

# go get the name of the last level, drop whatever it is
>>> df.droplevel(df.index.names[-1])

               col
this -1 other
1    5  1      foo
     3  2      bar
2    4  3      saz

# similarly...
>>> df.droplevel(df.index.names[0])

            col
-1 other 0
5  1     4  foo
3  2     8  bar
4  3     7  saz
```

Lastly, `droplevel` returns a new dataframe, so `df = df.droplevel(...)` is needed to see the change in `df`.