# Take the differences between groups of varying size in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I need to calculate the differences between consecutive time groups in data like the following

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

strio = StringIO("""\
               date  feat1         feat2  value
2016-10-15T00:00:00      1             1    0.0
2016-10-15T00:00:00      1             2    1.0
2016-10-15T00:00:00      2             1    2.0
2016-10-15T00:00:00      2             2    3.0
2016-10-15T00:01:00      1             1    8.0
2016-10-15T00:01:00      1             2    5.0
2016-10-15T00:02:00      1             1    8.0
2016-10-15T00:02:00      1             2   12.0
2016-10-15T00:02:00      2             1   10.0
2016-10-15T00:02:00      2             2   11.0
2016-10-15T00:03:00      1             1   12.0
2016-10-15T00:03:00      1             2   13.0
2016-10-15T00:03:00      2             1   14.0
2016-10-15T00:03:00      2             2   15.0""")
```

I can do this using `xarray` library

```
df = pd.read_table(strio, sep='\s+')
dims = df.columns.values[:3].tolist()
df.set_index(dims, inplace=True) # needed to convert to xarray dataset
dataset = df.to_xarray()
diff_time = dataset.diff(dim=dims[0]) # take the diff in time
print(diff_time.to_dataframe().reset_index())
```

prints

```
                   date  feat1  feat2  value
0   2016-10-15T00:01:00      1      1    8.0
1   2016-10-15T00:01:00      1      2    4.0
2   2016-10-15T00:01:00      2      1    NaN
3   2016-10-15T00:01:00      2      2    NaN
4   2016-10-15T00:02:00      1      1    0.0
5   2016-10-15T00:02:00      1      2    7.0
6   2016-10-15T00:02:00      2      1    NaN
7   2016-10-15T00:02:00      2      2    NaN
8   2016-10-15T00:03:00      1      1    4.0
9   2016-10-15T00:03:00      1      2    1.0
10  2016-10-15T00:03:00      2      1    4.0
11  2016-10-15T00:03:00      2      2    4.0
```

So in time instant 2016-10-15T00:01:00 that I have feat1:2 missing the relevant diffs are nan

How can I do this in pure pandas in a vectorized way? Constructing the original dataframe with nan fill-ins (so groups are equally sized) is an option but rather avoided

A clumsy way to do it would be:

```
dfs = []
for k, v in zip(itertools.islice(df.groupby(level=0).groups.values(), 1, None),
                df.groupby(level=0).groups.values()):
    # print(df.loc(axis=0)[k.values] , df.loc(axis=0)[v.values])
    diff = df.loc(axis=0)[k.values].reset_index(level=0, drop=True) - \
           df.loc(axis=0)[v.values].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    diff = pd.concat([diff], keys=[k.values[0][0]], names=['date'])
    dfs.append(diff)
print(pd.concat(dfs).reset_index())
```

It does print the same output but it is not vectorized

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the output? How are `feat1` and `feat2` relevant? Is every `value` 4 because you're trying to get the size of each `date` group? If so, is this close to what you're looking for: `df['value'] = df['date'].map(df.groupby('date').size())`?

Comment: Nope 4 is the difference between the same (feat1, feat2) subdataframes (each group that is). So this row `2016-10-15T00:01:00      1             1    4.0` minus that one (previous instance same feat1 and feat2) `2016-10-15T00:01:00      1             1    4.0` - when no feat1 or feat2 are present in next or previous instance I naturally get NaN

Comment: Note to self: drop index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085044/281545 and add it back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094658/281545, to explain the loop code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated solution:

```
df.unstack(0)['value']\
  .diff(axis=1)\
  .dropna(how='all', axis=1)\
  .unstack([0,1])\
  .rename('value')\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                   date  feat1  feat2  value
0   2016-10-15T00:01:00      1      1    8.0
1   2016-10-15T00:01:00      1      2    4.0
2   2016-10-15T00:01:00      2      1    NaN
3   2016-10-15T00:01:00      2      2    NaN
4   2016-10-15T00:02:00      1      1    0.0
5   2016-10-15T00:02:00      1      2    7.0
6   2016-10-15T00:02:00      2      1    NaN
7   2016-10-15T00:02:00      2      2    NaN
8   2016-10-15T00:03:00      1      1    4.0
9   2016-10-15T00:03:00      1      2    1.0
10  2016-10-15T00:03:00      2      1    4.0
11  2016-10-15T00:03:00      2      2    4.0
```

Details:

After creating a three level MultiIndex, first let's unstack level 0, date, which moves dates from rows to columns, then use diff on columns, lastly drop the the first date using dropna where the whole column is nan and unstack feat1 and feat2 to recreate multiindex and convert back to dataframe.

Comment: Wow impressive - I am accepting while trying to digest (especially this `transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]).unstack(0).diff(axis=1)` part, unstack escapes me)

Comment: Let me add the steps into the solution.

Comment: Basically, I am reshaping the dataframe that will let me use `diff` on columns easily and reshaping back to original form.

Comment: Hmmm I was a bit in a hurry I modified the example a bit, it does not produce the correct results for more irregular dataframe - the `d1 = df.groupby(level=[0])['value'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])` would need all values to appear, so I have to unaccept momentarily :P

Comment: No problem.  Yeah, if it gets more irregular it will become more complex. Such as missing dates, you will have to resample dates and etc... first.

Comment: See modified df - no I mean more irregular values - missing dates can also be present

Comment: Yeah... I think instead of groupby(level=[0]) only, let's try to groupby(level=[0,1,2]).  Which, I think simplifies the problem a bit.  We might not need groupby at all.

Comment: Hopefully :) The loop solution I posted still prints the correct result if it helps any

Comment: The only requirement is that dates are indeed ordered - but there may be gaps - loop solution still would work although clumsy as hell

Comment: Yey - thanks - feel free to remove initial solution as it did not really solve it, could use some explanation for `unstack(0)` which is the gist of it - so this moves the 'date' level to the columns and then we diff the columns IIUC